# Use of memory pools in C (Embedded systems)

Tags: c, memory, embedded, pool

I'm writing a piece of code for an embedded system (mcu Cortex-M4 with very limited ram < 32KB) where I need big chunks of memory for a very small and defined time and I thought to use some kind of a memory pool so the memory won't get wasted for functions and actions that run once or twice a lifetime.

I made some efforts but I think I'd like to learn more about memory pools and rewrite my code better.

I saw some examples where a pointer is used to point to the next available free chunk, but I don't understand how I can process those kind of pools.

[image]

For example, I can't use `strstr` in a memory pool where the total string would be spread into more than one chunk. I would need to read chunk by chunk and store the total string into one larger array to carry on further process. Please correct me if I'm wrong.

So, if I get it right, if I have a memory pool of 1024 bytes with 32 bytes long for each chunk that gives us 32 chunks in total. And if I want to store a string of total length let's say 256 chars (bytes) I'd need 8 chunks but if I want to read the string I'd need to copy those 8 chunks into a 256 chars array.

Am I missing something?

Comment: A block pool (with a 32-byte block) wouldn't work for a string greater than 31 (32 - 1) because it may be fragmented.

Comment: A linked list as shown in your diagram might be inefficient for what you want.  If you have 32 chunks then maybe just use a single word as a bitmap where each bit says whether the chunk is in use or not.  You could even use ldrex/strex to make it safe to allocate and free chunks in interrupt handlers.

Comment: However, I think a general purpose re-usable solution will always be less efficient than one which takes into account the specific purposes of each object.  For example, your "twice in a lifetime" event, if you need some memory briefly and then no more, could you put it on the stack?  Which temporary objects will you need to allocate and have persist after others are created and then be released before the ones created after it?

Comment: Existing heap allocators (e.g. `malloc` et. al.) use sophisticated subpools (arenas) to minimize fragmentation. So, whether you can do better depends upon the memory usage of your app. I think you ought to _edit_ your question and post representative code in a code block here. You might put some memory blocks on the stack. Or, do your own object specific allocation. What approach you take can depend upon what allocations must persist simultaneously.

Comment: I think your misgivings about the described situation are correct.  Having to stitch together multiple allocations from a memory pool would probably create more problems than it solves.  What you might be missing is that your chunks should be 256 bytes instead of 32 so that you can fit your maximum size string in one chunk.

Comment: This smells like an "XY problem". Why exactly do you "need big chunks of memory for a very small and defined time"? Understanding this is the key to proposing a solution. Is it because of some bootloader, or...?